# Bash: basename inconsistency when run in find

Tags: bash, find

Whole story: I am writing the script that will link all files from one directory to another. New file name will contain an original directory name. I use `find` at this moment with `-execdir` option.

This is how I want to use it:

```
./linkPictures.sh 2017_wien 2017/10
```

And it will create a symbolic link `2017_wien_picture.jp`g in `2017/10` pointing to a file `2017_wien/picture.jpg`.

This is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
UPLOAD="/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads"
SOURCE="$UPLOAD/photo-gallery/$1/"
DEST="$UPLOAD/$2/"
find $SOURCE -type f -execdir echo {} ";"
```

When I run

```
find . -execdir echo `basename {}` ";"
```

I receive:

```
./.
./DSC03278.JPG
```

Which is strange. So I ran it from command line:

```
basename ./DSC03278.JPG
```

and it works as expected:

```
DSC03278.JPG
```

Why `basename` does not work when invoked from `find` command? I think that the rest of script will be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a command like

```
foo bar `basename {}` baz
```

, the `` `...` `` part is expanded first. `` `basename {}` `` is `{}`, so this ends up running

```
foo bar {} baz
```

Similarly,

```
find . -execdir echo `basename {}` ";"
```

expands to

```
find . -execdir echo {} ";"
```

first and only then runs `find`.

Try

```
find . -execdir basename {} ";"
```

instead.

Comment: You would still want the `-type f` to prevent picking up the `.` file.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Nevertheless it makes the rest harder. I planned to do: find . -type d -execdir ln -s {} $dir/$dir_`basename {}`. Is it achievable with find?

Comment: I have accepted this answer and created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630069/strip-from-filename-in-find-execdir