# Strip ./ from filename in find -execdir

Tags: bash

Whole story: I am writing the script that will link all files from one directory to another. New file name will contain an original directory name. I use `find` at this moment with `-execdir` option.

This is how I want to use it:

```
./linkPictures.sh 2017_wien 2017/10
```

And it will create a symbolic link `2017_wien_picture.jpg` in `2017/10` pointing to a file `2017_wien/picture.jpg`.

This is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
UPLOAD="/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads"
SOURCE="$UPLOAD/photo-gallery/$1/"
DEST="$UPLOAD/$2/"
find $SOURCE -type f -execdir echo ln -s {} $DEST/"$1"_{} ";"
```

It prints:

```
ln -s ./DSC03278.JPG /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/pokus_./DSC03278.JPG
```

This is what I want:

```
ln -s ./DSC03278.JPG /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/pokus_DSC03278.JPG
```

How to implement it? I do not know how to incorporate `basename` into to strip ./.

Comment: I suggesto use `find -printf "%f\n"` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `basename` on `{}` you would need to execute a command through `sh`:

```
find "$SOURCE" -type f -execdir sh -c "echo ln -s '{}' \"$DEST/${1}_\$(basename \"{}\")\"" ";"
```

This won't win any speed contests (because of the `sh` for every file), but it will work.

All the quoting may look a bit crazy, but it's necessary to make it safe for files that may contain spaces.

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm! I have originally tried to run basename with ``, so I was quite close.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I saw your other question. On that note, an extra tip: always use `$(...)`, never the obsolete backticks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `find` with `bash -c`:

```
find $SOURCE -type f -execdir bash -c 'echo ln -s "$2" "/$DEST/$1"_${2#./}' - "$1" '{}'  \;
```

- `${2#./}` will strip starting `./` from each entry of `find` command's output.
- `$1` will be passed *as is* to `bash -c` command line.

If you have large number of files to process I suggest using this `while loop` using a process substitution for faster execution since it doesn't spawn a new bash for every file. Moreover it will also handle filenames with white-spaces and other special characters:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo ln -s "$file" "/$DEST/${1}_${file#./}"
done < <(find "$SOURCE" -type f -print0)
```